# Jquery Use Image As CheckBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am in pursuit of implementing images as checkboxes. For now I am trying out a sample.
The code below contains a simple image with a submit button next to it. On clicking the submit button I want the image to develop a border around it and on clicking the submit button, I want the checkbox value to be passed.

```
<html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#blr').click(
        function(){
            $('#blr').css('border', 'solid 2px red');
            $('#imgCheck').attr('checked', 'checked');
        },
        function(){
            $('#blr').css('border', 'none');
            $('#imgCheck').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    );
});
</script>

<form id="form1">
    <img src="icons/blr.jpg" title="blr" id="blr" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="imgCheck" name="imgCheck" value="barney" style="visibility: hidden;" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

I am relatively new to Jquery and I am not able to figure out where am I going wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: **Note:** You should use .prop() instead of .attr() when working with property values

Comment: Please add `<body>` and/or `<head>` tags at appropriate places in your html

Comment: You can use pure CSS to style the checkbox

Comment: as @TheYaXxE said it can be done with HTML&CSS only - **please check my answer for HTML&CSS only solution**

Comment: For future reference, take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663562/use-images-like-checkboxes and, since you're using jQuery, I'll do a shameless plug; see this plugin: https://jcuenod.github.io/imgCheckbox/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution of your question. I hope this will help you.

CSS

```
.checked {border:solid 2px red}
```

HTML Code

```
<form id="form1">
    <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows-8-metro-style/128/unchecked_checkbox.png" title="blr" id="blr" class="" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="imgCheck" name="imgCheck" value="barney" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#blr').on('click', function(){
        var $$ = $(this)
        if( !$$.is('.checked')){
            $$.addClass('checked');
            $('#imgCheck').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $$.removeClass('checked');
            $('#imgCheck').prop('checked', false);
        }
    })

});
```

Working Example : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3u2Le/6/)

Comment: Click the image multiple times and you'll see the checkbox is not getting checked, you should use .prop() http://jsfiddle.net/3u2Le/5/

Comment: I see how the demo is working and it is exactly what I want. I have just copied and pasted your code and yet I am not getting the desired output. I have changed the image source but I am not able to figure out what has gone wrong.

Comment: @Anton: Thanks for your feedback...It's working fine now after muliple times we clicked on image

Comment: @Rakesh Kumar http://jsfiddle.net/3u2Le/8/ - This is the fiddle. Its just the same as yours. Its working here. I believe there is something more trivial that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 3):

Actually using image as checkbox **can be done with HTML & CSS ONLY**!

The trick is to style a `<label>` element (make it an image) and add it a `for="checkboxid"` parameter - then just make a `<checkbox>` with a proper `id="checkboxid"` and hide it. When you click on label => the checkbox gets (un)checked. Also the usage of `:checked` and `+` selector is good if you want to change label image on checked / unchecked.

## HTML

```
<input id="checkboxid" type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox">
<label for="checkboxid" class="css-label"></label>
```

## CSS

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox{ display: none; }
.css-label{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left:20px;
    height:15px;
    background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/dark-check-green.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
    background-position: 0 -15px;
}
```

Fiddle - **edited**/simplified: http://jsfiddle.net/bdTX2/

Example took from: http://www.csscheckbox.com/

Comment: I do like this solution as it does not rely on JS. I took the concept a bit further in this JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/coolwebs/bz5z5yhx/18/

Answer (score 0):

Click doesn't work like that, you can't toggle two functions. You must use an if statement like this

```
$('#blr').click(function () {
    var chk = $('#imgCheck').get(0);
    if (!chk.checked) {
        $(this).css('border', 'solid 2px red');
        $('#imgCheck').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).css('border', 'none');
        $('#imgCheck').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3u2Le/2/)

You could shorten the code even more like this

```
$('#blr').click(function () {
    var chk = $('#imgCheck').get(0);
        $(this).css('border', !chk.checked?'solid 2px red':'none');
        $('#imgCheck').prop('checked', !chk.checked);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3u2Le/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The click Function doesn't work like what your thinking.... the way you are looking for is for Toggle Try this ..I think This Will help ..Cheers

```
$('#blr').toggle(function () {
    $("#blr").css('border', 'solid 2px red');
    $('#imgCheck').prop('checked', false);
}, function () {
    $('#blr').css('border', 'none');
$('#imgCheck').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: `toggle(function(){},function(){})` is deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9 http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

Comment: @Anton Thanks.. i don't have right to +1 this question ..but it should be given because learned a new thing..:)

Comment: The answer is still correct, but the thing is removed/deprecated functions should be noted.

Comment: yeah..will keep that in Mind...@Anton

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#blr').on('click', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $imgCheck = $(this).next().attr('checked'),
        border_styles = ['solid 2px red', 'none']
        is_checked = $imgCheck.attr('checked');
    $this.css('border', border_styles[is_checked]);
    $imgCheck.attr('checked', !is_checked);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution for **CSS-Only**

Use `-webkit-apperance: none` to 'hide' the original checkbox, and then style it as you want.

To style, when checkbox is checked, simple use this pseudo code: `input[type="checkbox"]:checked`

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

**CSS**

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    background: url(http://2012.igem.org/wiki/images/7/79/Small-checkmark.png) center no-repeat;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheYaXxE/9QRbC/)