# jQuery custom checkboxes + hidden html checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm making a grid of divs that can be toggled on and off. I need to post the values of these toggled divs to a database.

Currently I have jQuery waiting for clicks on the divs and then changing checkbox values on a hidden checkbox element...

```
$('.icon').click(function(){
    var checkValue = $(this).attr("data-c");
    // Then tick hidden checkbox where data-c = checkbox
});
```

As I end up posting this data with ajax, is there a better way to do this?

Here's what it looks like:
[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually **don't need JS**.
Use a `<label>` elements to wrap your checkbox and a span.
Change the style of that inner `span` using the `input:checked` next sibling selector `+`:

```css
label.icon span{
  cursor:  pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width:   75px;
  height:  75px;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceycQ.jpg) no-repeat;
  border:  3px solid #0186C9;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
label.icon input{ /* hide the checkbox */
  position:   absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
label.icon input:checked + span{ /* when input is checked */
  background-position: 0 -75px;
}
```

```html
<form action="">

  <label class="icon">
    <input type="checkbox" name="dog">
    <span></span>
  </label>

</form>
```

on `form` submit you'll submit all the correct data without a single line of JS

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was after. Thanks for interpreting my not so great explanation! Ever since I've become somewhat competent with JS I've been really over using it. This is a good reminder to be a bit more conservative.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a similar question here: [Jquery Use Image As CheckBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628524/jquery-use-image-as-checkbox)

As an alternative to storing the value in a check box you could store it in a object? For example:

```
window.icons = {};
$('.icon').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('identifier');
    window.icons[id] = !!window.icons[id];
});
```

Also check out this example for a similar use http://jsfiddle.net/bdTX2/