# Use images like checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like to have an alternative to a standard checkbox - basically I'd like to use images and when the user clicks the image, fade it out and overlay a tick box.

In essence, I want to do something like Recaptcha 2 does when it gets you to click images that meet a certain criteria. You can [see a Recaptcha demo here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) but it might sometimes get you to solve text questions, as opposed to the image selection. So here's a screenshot:

[image: Google Recaptcha screenshot]

When you click one of the images (in this case, containing a picture of steak), the image you click shrinks in size and the blue tick appears, indicating that you've ticked it.

Let's say I want to reproduce this exact example.

I realise I can have 9 hidden checkboxes, and attach some jQuery so that when I click the image, it selects/deselects the hidden checkbox. But what about the shrinking of the image/overlaying the tick?

Comment: you can have two identical images: one with tick and other is without tick. And change images on click

Comment: @Alex That would be a particularly unflexible solution.

Comment: @Siguza you need to explain what do u mean by "unflexibl solution"?

Comment: Have you tried adding/removing a CSS class on click that overrides the image size and does some `:before` magic for the tick image?

Comment: @Hexaholic No, I didn't think about it, but that seems like a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an updated example to my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30664019/3296661 - You can tweak it to work how you want it to work.

Comment: @Alex "Unflexible" in the sense that it would require a lot more work to change anything, like adding a new picture to the collection or changing the "ticked" icon, when this would not be the case if the effect is programatically created at runtime.

Comment: @Christian Replacing checkboxes with a custom something is a popular design decision (even if it's just a styled checkbox), and finding good/simple ways to do it is definitely of interest to devs who've had to deal with it.  And this question (overlaying the checkbox replacement on something else) definitely makes it an interesting one.  In particular, note how the accepted answer uses no JS at all, despite the apparent complexity of the task

Comment: If you only want to use images (without checkboxes and labels etc.) I have added an additional jQuery solution.

Comment: How about this amazing(!) plugin: http://jcuenod.github.io/imgCheckbox/ ;)

Comment: @dippas: The duplicate closing is [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381595/mark-as-duplicate-after-2-5-years)

Answer (score 351, accepted):

## Pure semantic HTML/CSS solution

This is easy to implement on your own, no pre-made solution necessary. Also it will teach you a lot as you don't seem too easy with CSS.

### This is what you need to do:

Your checkboxes need to have distinct `id` attributes. This allows you to connect a `<label>` to it, using the label's `for`-attribute.

Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox1" />
<label for="myCheckbox1"><img src="http://someurl" /></label>
```

Attaching the label to the checkbox will trigger a browser behaviour: Whenever someone clicks the label (or the image inside it), the checkbox will be toggled.

Next, you hide the checkbox by applying for example `display: none;` to it.

Now all that is left to do is set the style you want for your `label::before` pseudo element (which will be used as the visual checkbox replacement elements):

```
label::before {
    background-image: url(../path/to/unchecked.png);
}
```

In a last tricky step, you make use of CSS' `:checked` pseudo selector to change the image when the checkbox is checked:

```
:checked + label::before {
    background-image: url(../path/to/checked.png);
}
```

The `+` (*adjacent sibling selector*) makes sure you only change labels that directly follow the hidden checkbox in the markup.

You can optimize that by putting both images in a spritemap and only applying a change in `background-position` instead of swapping the image.

Of course you need to position the label correctly and apply `display: block;` and set correct `width` and `height`.

### Edit:

The codepen example and snippet, which I created after these instructions, use the same technique, **but instead of using images for the checkboxes, the checkbox replacements are done purely with CSS**, creating a `::before` on the label that, once checked, has `content: "✓";`. Add some rounded borders and sweet transitions and the result is really likable!

Here is a working codepen that showcases the technique and doesn't require images for the checkbox:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wadwpx

Here is the same code in a snippet:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

label::before {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

:checked+label {
  border-color: #ddd;
}

:checked+label::before {
  content: "✓";
  background-color: grey;
  transform: scale(1);
}

:checked+label img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
    <label for="cb1"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/1/100" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
    <label for="cb2"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/2/100" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" />
    <label for="cb3"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/3/100" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" />
    <label for="cb4"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/4/100" /></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Glad you like it! Start fiddling around with CSS more, it's alot of fun and CSS can do so much more than you'd probably ever expect (except vertical centering, that's just too difficult ;) ).

Comment: Yeah, and understanding the way it works will make you think in the future, every time you want some DOM action on click. And you thought you can react only to `:hover` :)

Comment: That'll be my next thing to watch on Pluralsight - some CSS stuff :)

Comment: This is very nice! 
I noticed a small problem when you click the same label twice, it selects the image. This fixes it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPmNjg

Comment: Just another application of the same technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664262/change-of-background-using-css/

Comment: @AyeshK more helpful to just say use: `user-select: none;`

Comment: @connexo this is a great solution and I LOVE the end result. The thing I still don't like about your *answer* though is that you aren't explaining most of the code you end up with; your answer doesn't match your solution.

Comment: The linked codesnippet actually doesn't replace the picture like you proposed in your answer, but instead scales it to 0.9 and adds a checked icon to the label. The other diffrences are simple some styling, but you really should edit your answer to match your snippet (which is actually a prettier solution than two images).

Comment: "This is easy to implement on your own and you'll learn a lot." *Proceeds to hand OP almost complete solution.*

Comment: Hey, this is awesome! Would've never thought about wrapping labels around images.

Comment: Tick would've looked better as SVG. CSS content puts you at the mercy of some terrible system fonts.

Comment: Nice solution, the only thing I would add would be to give the labels a common class and then use that to access them. This would make it modular and allow for traditional labels elsewhere on the same page.

Comment: @MrMadsen Sure, but for a concise example, I like to omit stuff like that to keep the code short.

Comment: If you put your checkbox inside the label tag, you don't need `for` or a matching `id`. Example: `<label><input type="checkbox" /><img src="http://someurl" /></label>`.

Comment: @rybo111 This is trivial, but it wrecks the whole idea since in CSS  you cannot select "upwards" this would not allow you to style the label differently depending on checked state. And no, you cannot use `:before` or `:after` on the checkbox itself since it cannot have `content`.

Comment: Since the label is just for click detection you don't need to style it. Just style a sibling to the input.

Comment: @rybo111 That would require additional, unnecessary markup. I like to have the markup as lean as possible.

Comment: The `img` elements inside the `label` elements need an `alt` attribute for accessibility reasons. Or you should provide an alternative CAPTCHA that does not rely on vision.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe This was never meant to be the 100% everything-covered solution, it just demonstrates a technical solution for a given problem. And also, the question never was "how do I make images as checkboxes accessible". I see you care alot about accessibility, but it starts to get a missionary taste which I don't like.

Comment: lorempixel.com placeholders are not available. It's a possible dead service. I've updated the example using placekitten.com - https://codepen.io/naxa777/pen/QJGZbW

Comment: @naxa I'm not experiencing any downtimes so far on lorempixel service.

Comment: @connexo Is there a way to select ONLY one image at a time?

Comment: @VijayRana So that selecting a different image will deselect the previously selected one?

Comment: @connexo Yes, exactly. One selection at a time.

Comment: Replace `type="checkbox"` with `type="radio" name="foo"` on all `input`s, and you have just that. Also adjust `input[type="checkbox"]` in the CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 34):

## Pure CSS Solution

There are three neat devices invoked:

1. The [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) selector
2. The [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-selector
3. The css [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property.

```css
label:before {
  content: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/unchecked_checkbox.png");
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
:checked+label:before {
  content: url("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/windows8_icons_iconpharm/26/checked_checkbox.png");
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
/*pure cosmetics:*/
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
label {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox1" />
<label for="myCheckbox1">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR0LkgDZRDTgnDrzhnXGDFRSItAzGCBEWEnkLMdnA_zkIH5Zg6oag">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox2" />
<label for="myCheckbox2">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhJjGB3mQxjhI5lfS9SwXou06-2qT_0MjNAr0atu75trXIaR2d">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox3" />
<label for="myCheckbox3">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQuwWbUXC-lgzQHp-j1iw56PIgl_2eALrEENUP-ld72gq3s8cVo">
</label>
```

Comment: How it possible to add a radio button behavior to these checkboxes? I mean when you click on an image the already selected image become deselected.

Comment: Whoever asking himself the same question as @Libertad just change the inputs type to radio and give them all the same name "attribute" `<input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio1" />` also change your css to hide the bullet : `input[type=radio]{display: none;}`

Answer (score 8):

**See this jQuery plugin: [imgCheckbox](https://jcuenod.github.io/imgCheckbox/)** (on **[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imgcheckbox)** and **[bower](http://bower.io/search/?q=imgcheckbox)**)

**Disclaimer:** No javascript is necessary to solve this problem. The tension is between maintainability and efficiency of code. While there's no need for a plugin (or any javascript), it sure does make it faster to build and often easier to change.

## Barebones Solution:

With very **simple HTML** (none of the mess with checkboxes and labels etc.):

```
<img class="checkable" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
```

You can use jQuery's **toggleClass** to turn on/off a `selected` or `checked` class on the `click` event:

```
$("img.checkable").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("checked");
});
```

Checked items are fetched with

```
$(".checked")
```

## Plus Coolness:

You can style the images based off of this but a big problem is that without other DOM elements you can't even use `::before` and `::after` to add stuff like check marks. The solution is to wrap your images with another element (and it makes sense to attach the click listener to the wrapped element as well).

```
$("img.checkable").wrap("<span class='fancychecks'>")
```

This leaves your html really clean and your js incredibly readable. Take a look at the snippet...

```js
/* Note that this js actually responds
   to a click event on the wrapped element!
   (not the image) */
$("img.checkable").wrap("<span class='fancychecks'>")
  .parent().click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("checked");
  });
```

```css
/* style the images */
span.fancychecks img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  transform: scale(1);
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
span.fancychecks.checked img {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  filter: gray;
  filter: grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}

/* style the parent spans */
span.fancychecks {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}
span.fancychecks.checked {
  border-color: #ccc;
}

/* Using conexo's fantastic CSS, make the checkmarks */
span.fancychecks::before {
  background-color: rgba(50, 200, 50, 0.7);
  color: white;
  content: "✓";
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2px;
  top: 1;
  left: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}
span.fancychecks.checked::before {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="checkable" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/1" />
<img class="checkable" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/2" />
<img class="checkable" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/city/3" />
```

## Using the [imgCheckbox](http://jcuenod.github.io/imgCheckbox/) jQuery Plugin:

Inspired by the solution above, I have built a plugin which can be used as easily as:

```
$("img").imgCheckbox();
```

- Injects the data for checked images into your form
- Supports custom check marks
- Supports customised CSS
- Supports preselected elements
- Supports radio groups instead of simple toggling of images
- Has event callbacks
- Sensible defaults
- Lightweight and super easy to use

See it **[in action](http://jcuenod.github.io/imgCheckbox/)** (and [see the source](https://github.com/jcuenod/imgCheckbox))

Comment: I like this approach as well, but it has a number of downsides which are worth mentioning, the biggest being this: Assuming the user is meant to choose images, the information given by the user this way is surely meant to be processed somehow, be it via an AJAX call or via a form submit. For the pruposes of further processing of the information given by the user, having checkboxes where a number of choices have to be reflected and processed is just the natural, semantic way of doing it.

Comment: This is true, it's on my todo list for the plugin - to hijack form submission and inject the data into the form. But you're right, checkboxes are semantic for forms

Comment: I tried using your plugin, but if I'm adding more images after the initialization there doesn't seem to be a way to destroy the previous instance so that the new images can be included

Comment: @IanKim interesting use case, can you explain more about what you're trying to do in an issue on github? https://github.com/jcuenod/imgCheckbox

Comment: It's an awesome plugin! please publish a Webjar =)

Answer (score 6):

I would append an extra div with `position: relative;` and `class="checked"` which has the same width/height as the image has and than position in `left: 0; top: 0;` containing the icon. It starts with `display: none;`.

Now you can listen to the `click`-event:

```
$( '.captcha_images' ).click( function() {
    $(this + '.checked').css( 'display', 'block' );
    $(this).animate( { width: '70%', height: '70%' } );
});
```

This way you can get the icon and also resize the image to a smaller way.

Notice: Just wanted to show you the "logic" behind my thoughts, this example might not work or has some bugs in it.

Comment: The technique I demonstrated is so simple and robust, it is even often applied in situations where you don't have any checkboxes semantically, like toggling the display of other elements and the like. **This** is the usecase where it is not only the easiest, most flexible solution, but also the semantically best.

Comment: Yes, you're right. At first I wanted to point out your first answer and improve it (before editing), because I like No-JS and nice Semantic ways, but than I read that the OP wants something in jQuery so I changed my answer. I remember where I got a downvote, because the OP didn't want a "better" or "the right way" solution, but the exact way he wrote. Maybe there is just something I overread or didn't understant or it depends on the OP?

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed other answers either don't use `<label>` (why not?), or require matching `for` and `id` attributes. This means if you have clashing IDs, your code won't work, and you must remember to make unique IDs each time.

Also, if you hide the `input` with `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`, the browser will not focus on it.

A checkbox and its text (or in this case, image) can be wrapped in a label:

```css
.fancy-checkbox-label > input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: inherit;
}
.fancy-checkbox-label {
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fancy-checkbox:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f00c";
  background: #fff;
  color: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.fancy-checkbox-label:hover > .fancy-checkbox:before,
input:focus + .fancy-checkbox:before {
  border-color: #bdbdff;
}
.fancy-checkbox-label:hover > input:not(:checked) + .fancy-checkbox:before {
  color: #eee;
}
input:checked + .fancy-checkbox:before {
  color: #fff;
  background: #bdbdff;
  border-color: #bdbdff;
}
.fancy-checkbox-img:before {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 3px;
  line-height: normal;
}
input:checked + .fancy-checkbox-img + img {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #bdbdff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T8Gy5hrqNKT+hzMclPo118YTQO6cYprQmhrYwIiQ/3axmI1hQomh7Ud2hPOy8SP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<p>
  <label class="fancy-checkbox-label">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="fancy-checkbox"></span>
    A normal checkbox
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label class="fancy-checkbox-label">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="fancy-checkbox fancy-checkbox-img"></span>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/1/100">
  </label>
</p>
```

Comment: This solution uses additional markup, which now thanks to the `:has()` pseudoselector function is no longer necessary.

Comment: I like your solution withour IDs and yust wrapping labels, but your image `http://placehold.it/150x150` can not be loaded what makes your example less impressiv because I cant see an example with custom images

Answer (score 3):

I made an example of **"Angular - Use images like checkboxes and radios"**

[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-base-simple-scss-hf9hrp?file=src/app/app.component.html)

[image]

[image]

In app.component.html file:

```
<div class="cont-bg">
  <h5 class="text-white">Checkbox</h5>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox" *ngFor="let car of cars; index as i">
      <input type="checkbox" [id]="'myCheckbox-' + i" />
      <label [for]="'myCheckbox-' + i">
        <img [src]="car.img" />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">{{ car.name }}</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h5 class="text-white">Radio</h5>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox" *ngFor="let car of cars; index as i">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" [id]="'myRadio-' + i" />
      <label [for]="'myRadio-' + i">
        <img [src]="car.img" />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">{{ car.name }}</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In app.component.scss file:

```
* {
  font-family: Lato;
  --transition: 0.15s;
  --border-radius: 0.5rem;
  --background: #ffc107;
  --box-shadow: #ffc107;
  // --box-shadow: #0082ff;
}

.cont-bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle farthest-corner at 7.2% 13.6%,
    rgba(37, 249, 245, 1) 0%,
    rgba(8, 70, 218, 1) 90%
  );
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-checkbox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  transition: transform var(--transition);
  background: white;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
  &:active {
    transform: scale(0.9);
  }
  input {
    display: none;
    &:checked + label {
      opacity: 1;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--background);
      .cover-checkbox {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
        svg {
          stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
      }
      img {
        -webkit-filter: none; /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
        filter: none;
      }
    }
  }
  label {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.6;
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 70%;
      object-fit: cover;
      clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 81%, 50% 100%, 0 81%);
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
      filter: grayscale(100%);
    }
    .cover-checkbox {
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
      top: 3px;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 23px;
      height: 23px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: var(--box-shadow);
      border: 2px solid #fff;
      transition: transform var(--transition),
        opacity calc(var(--transition) * 1.2) linear;
      opacity: 0;
      transform: scale(0);
      svg {
        width: 13px;
        height: 11px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        fill: none;
        margin: 5px 0 0 3px;
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 2;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
        stroke-dasharray: 16px;
        transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.4s ease var(--transition);
        stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
      }
    }
    .info {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 0.2rem;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-size: 0.8rem;
    }
  }
}
```

In app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  cars = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Mazda MX-5 Miata',
      img: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'Toyota Supra',
      img: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Chevy Corvette',
      img: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-porsche-cayman-mmp-1-1593003674.jpg?crop=0.648xw:0.485xh;0.129xw,0.263xh&resize=980:*',
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      name: 'Porsche 718 Cayman',
      img: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-porsche-718-cayman-mmp-1-1593003156.jpg?crop=0.735xw:0.551xh;0.138xw,0.240xh&resize=980:*',
    },
    {
      id: '5',
      name: 'Porsche 718 Boxster',
      img: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-bmw-m2-mmp-1-1599687968.jpg?crop=0.706xw:0.528xh;0.102xw,0.268xh&resize=980:*',
    },
    {
      id: '6',
      name: 'BMW M2',
      img: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-bmw-z4-mmp-1-1599583762.jpg?crop=0.779xw:0.584xh;0.0782xw,0.196xh&resize=980:*',
    },
    {
      id: '7',
      name: 'BMW Z4',
      img: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-chevrolet-camaro-mmp-1-1585333717.jpg?crop=0.344xw:0.331xh;0.241xw,0.328xh&resize=980:*',
    },
    {
      id: '8',
      name: 'Chevy Camaro',
      img: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-chevrolet-camaro-zl1-mmp-1-1604071262.jpg?crop=0.818xw:0.663xh;0.0799xw,0.163xh&resize=980:*',
    },
    {
      id: '9',
      name: 'Chevy Camaro ZL1',
      img: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-chevrolet-camaro-zl1-mmp-1-1604071262.jpg?crop=0.818xw:0.663xh;0.0799xw,0.163xh&resize=768:*',
    },
  ];
}
```

**Pure CSS Checkbox and Radio:**

```css
* {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --transition: 0.15s;
  --border-radius: 0.5rem;
  --background: #ffc107;
  --box-shadow: #ffc107;
}

.cont-bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle farthest-corner at 7.2% 13.6%,
    rgba(37, 249, 245, 1) 0%,
    rgba(8, 70, 218, 1) 90%
  );
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.cont-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-checkbox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  background: white;
  transition: transform var(--transition);
}

.cont-checkbox:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
}

.cont-checkbox:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--background);
}

input:checked + label img {
  -webkit-filter: none; /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: none;
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

label img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 81%, 50% 100%, 0 81%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

label .cover-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--box-shadow);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: transform var(--transition),
    opacity calc(var(--transition) * 1.2) linear;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label .cover-checkbox svg {
  width: 13px;
  height: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  fill: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0 3px;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.4s ease var(--transition);
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
}

label .info {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-bg">
  <div class="cont-title">Checkbox</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-1" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-2" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont-title">Radio</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-1" />
      <label for="myRadio-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-2" />
      <label for="myRadio-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a quick example of selecting an image like a checkbox

**Updated Example using Knockout.js:**

```js
var imageModel = function() {
    this.chk = ko.observableArray();
};
ko.applyBindings(new imageModel());
```

```css
    input[type=checkbox] {
        display:none;
      }
 
  input[type=checkbox] + label
   {
       display:inline-block;
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        background:#FBDFDA;
        border:none;
   }
   
   input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
    {
        background:#CFCFCF;
        border:none;
        position:relative;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        padding: 20px;
    }

   input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after
    {
        content: '\2713';
        position:absolute;
        top:-10px;
        right:-10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        border-color: white;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' name='image1' value='image1' id="image1" data-bind="checked: chk"/><label for="image1"></label><label for="image1"><img class='testbtn'/></label>

<div data-bind="html: chk"></div>
```

Comment: While I like the your approach, it would be helpful for most to state that you are using Knockout.js in your example.

Comment: @connexo Cheers, just updated to say example using Knockout.js

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the accepted answer for anyone using WordPress & GravityForms to generate their forms and wish to automatically populate checkbox fields with a list of posts and their associated Featured Thumbnail

```
// Change '2' to your form ID
add_filter( 'gform_pre_render_2', 'populate_checkbox' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_validation_2', 'populate_checkbox' );
add_filter( 'gform_pre_submission_filter_2', 'populate_checkbox' );
add_filter( 'gform_admin_pre_render_2', 'populate_checkbox' );

function populate_checkbox( $form ) {

    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field )  {

        // Change '41' to your checkbox field ID
        $field_id = 41;
        if ( $field->id != $field_id ) {
            continue;
        }

        // Adjust $args for your post type
        $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'pet',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'pet_category',
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => 'cat'
                        )
                )
        );

        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        $input_id = 1;

        foreach( $posts as $post ) {

            $feat_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'thumbnail' );
            $feat_image_url .= '<br />' . $post->post_title;

            if ( $input_id % 10 == 0 ) {
                $input_id++;
            }

            $choices[] = array( 'text' => $feat_image_url, 'value' => $post->post_title );
            $inputs[] = array( 'label' => $post->post_title, 'id' => "{$field_id}.{$input_id}" );

            $input_id++;
        }

        $field->choices = $choices;
        $field->inputs = $inputs;

    }

    return $form;
}
```

And the CSS:

```
.gform_wrapper .gfield_checkbox li[class^="gchoice_2_41_"] {
    display: inline-block;
}

.gform_wrapper .gfield_checkbox li input[type="checkbox"][id^="choice_2_41_"] {
    display: none;
}


.gform_wrapper .gfield_checkbox li label[id^="label_2_41_"] {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

label[id^="label_2_41_"]:before {
    font-family: "font-icons";
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #1abc9c;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transform: scale(0);
}

label[id^="label_2_41_"] img {
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

:checked + label[id^="label_2_41_"] {
    border-color: #ddd;
}

/* FontAwesome tick */
:checked + label[id^="label_2_41_"]:before {
    content: "\e6c8";
    background-color: transparent;
    transform: scale(1);
}

:checked + label[id^="label_2_41_"] img {
    transform: scale(0.9);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
    z-index: 0;
}
```