# Change of background using CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Is it possible to change background image of page by click on button using only CSS? I have 6 buttons, and I want to change background image of whole page to be changed on button click.

Is it possible with only css? If yes, then how?

Comment: just change the css class on click

Comment: You need to use some Javascript. I'd change the class of my `<body>` tag by clicking on that button. Then CSS takes care of the background (and every other style-related thing you might want to change) depending on that class.

Comment: You need to add some javascript for the click event, and if you want to change image only css then you can use the hover effect.

Comment: CSS determine how page should look like, not how it should behave. Without any scripting it's not possible to change background of page by clicking on button.

Comment: Simply put. Answer = NO

Comment: This is possible with CSS only, and very easy.

Comment: I've added the extremely simply CSS based solution below. It's astonishing that people that don't seem to have a clue of what CSS is capable of keep answering "is this possible with CSS only"-questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That would be nice, but no.

You don't need that hard a function, though. Simply attach the background change with the rest of the functionality of the button. I recommend in this case that you just add the background image as css inline with your js, because 6 classes of images can go wrong easy.

Comment: OP: Please uncheck this answer as it is plain wrong.
@Vlad Pintea: Since your answer is just wrong, it'd be helpful for all if you could delete it.

Answer (score 4):

This is perfectly easily possible using only CSS and HTML.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpmPYO

```css
input[name="bg-change-control"] {
  display: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#page {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1000/700) no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

label {
  -moz-appearance: button;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

#cb1:checked ~ #page{
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600);
}
#cb2:checked ~ #page{
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/640/480);
}
#cb3:checked ~ #page{
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1024/768);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="bg-change-control" id="cb1" />
<input type="radio" name="bg-change-control" id="cb2" />
<input type="radio" name="bg-change-control" id="cb3" />

<div id="page">
  <label for="cb1">BG 1</label>
  <label for="cb2">BG 2</label>
  <label for="cb3">BG 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: this is a perfect answer. But i suggest some modification such as `postion:fixed;  overflow:scroll;` which will help to not to show original bg when the content has overflow;

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with pure CSS and HTML. No need to use Javascript and Jquery.

Try this

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Click" class="click">
<div class="background1"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.background1 {
    background: url("http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Category-Creative/UK/UK_Creative_462809583.jpg") no-repeat; width:500px; height:500px
}
.click:focus ~ .background1 {
    background: url("http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/01/06/2473100D00000578-2898639-Photographer_Andrey_Gudkov_snapped_the_images_on_the_plains_of_t-a-20_1420546215677.jpg") no-repeat; width:500px; height:500px
}
```

Hope it will fullfil your requirement.