# Using image for checkbox input

Tags: html, css

First, please do not mark this as duplicate, cause I want to ask a little modification from this QnA, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663562/use-images-like-checkboxes/30663705). I'm using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30663705/10454516) to achieve what I want, but it almost meets what I need. Here is his [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wadwpx).

I am trying to achieve what he did, [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPzYOv#anon-signup) is what I've made so far. But, when I click the image, because of the border, it makes the images a little get bigger. What I want is, when the image (checkbox) checked, there are checkboxes icon on the top left (its done) and the image surrounds with a border without making the image get bigger. Here is the code in my snippet:

here is the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
    <label for="cb1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/103/103" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
    <label for="cb2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/102/102" /></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this is the CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}    
li {
  display: inline-block;
}    
input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
  display: none;
}    
label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}    
label:before {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.4s;
}    
label img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}    
:checked + label {
  border-color: red;
}    
:checked + label:before {
  content: "✓";
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 99;
}    
:checked + label img {
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Border for img with transparent

```
label img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVRxRM

Answer (score 0):

So if requirement is when you click on image, you need to show `✓` on left top corner of image, and you also want to show some border around image, then what you have done is absolutely right.

If you are concerned about image moving by `n` pixel, then keep in mind that `border` occupy some space unlike `outline` which doesnt need any space. `Outline` takes `n` pixel around object and apply border type effect.

So there are 2 solution -

1. what @lalji suggested above.  when you load page, apply border on image with color as `transparent` so it will reserve the space for your border and actually you will not see any border around it, and on clicking (selecting image) just change the color of border.

[Fiddle for border transparent](https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/q5sLb6cm/5)

```
label img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

2. another will be when you click it, apply the outline instead of border.

[Fiddle for outline](https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/q5sLb6cm/4)

```
:checked + label img {
  z-index: -1;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

3. **UPADTE** if we want to show some image/text also when image selected. if you see here I have added another node saying `details` that will be shown only when image selected and will be aligned in centre of the image.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stdeepak22/q5sLb6cm/18/)

This below css rule to hide the details initially and making them in centre etc.

```
label img + .details
{
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px; 
  width:100%;  
  display:none;
  margin-top:50%;
  transform: translatey(-50%);
  text-align:center;
}
```

Now, we will show the `details` section if image selected.

```
:checked + label img + .details
{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: did you know what if I want to add image and also text inside the label? what you gave, It works perfectly. But, I forgot to add one thing, what I have to make is a checkbox as you gave above PLUS an img and text inside it. So, the first image is as the background, and the second image is as the label with additional text. Pardon for my english, but did u get what I mean? If u could help, it will really means a lot.

Comment: sorry to say but I didnt get you.  Can you please pass-on some sample what exatly you need? did you need like when we click to select you need `+` in centre of image with text instead of `✓`.  pls provide sample image?

Comment: I've update my code snippet https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WPzYOv#anon-signup, but still dont know how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

I gave fixed height and width to li and when the checkbox is checked i am changing the height and width of an image and aligning it in the center. hope this is what you are looking for. thanks.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 120px;
}

label:before {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

label img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

:checked + label {
  border-color: red;
}

:checked + label:before {
  content: "✓";
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 99;
}

:checked + label img {
  z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
    <label for="cb1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
    <label for="cb2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/101/101" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb3" />
    <label for="cb3"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/102/102" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb4" />
    <label for="cb4"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/103/103" /></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type="checkbox"][id^="cb"] {
  display: none;
}
label {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:before {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transform: scale(0);
}
label img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
:checked + label {
  border-color: red;
}
:checked + label:before {
  content: "✓";
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 99;
  transform: scale(1);
}
:checked + label img {
  z-index: -1;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
    <label for="cb1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/103/103" /></label>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="cb2" />
    <label for="cb2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/102/102" /></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use a **"label"** tag that contains an **"img"** tag inside.

Here's an example of using an image as a checkbox and radio.

```css
* {
  font-family: Lato;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  --transition: 0.15s;
  --border-radius: 0.5rem;
  --background: #ffc107;
  --box-shadow: #ffc107;
}

.cont-bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
    circle farthest-corner at 7.2% 13.6%,
    rgba(37, 249, 245, 1) 0%,
    rgba(8, 70, 218, 1) 90%
  );
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.cont-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.cont-checkbox {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.25rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  background: white;
  transition: transform var(--transition);
}

.cont-checkbox:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  margin-right: 0.75rem;
}

.cont-checkbox:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px var(--background);
}

input:checked + label img {
  -webkit-filter: none; /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: none;
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}

input:checked + label .cover-checkbox svg {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

label img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  object-fit: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 81%, 50% 100%, 0 81%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

label .cover-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--box-shadow);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: transform var(--transition),
    opacity calc(var(--transition) * 1.2) linear;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}

label .cover-checkbox svg {
  width: 13px;
  height: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  fill: none;
  margin: 5px 0 0 3px;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-dasharray: 16px;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 0.4s ease var(--transition);
  stroke-dashoffset: 16px;
}

label .info {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0.2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont-bg">
  <div class="cont-title">Checkbox</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-1" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox-2" />
      <label for="myCheckbox-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cont-title">Radio</div>
  <div class="cont-main">
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-1" />
      <label for="myRadio-1">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2021-mazda-mx-5-miata-mmp-1-1593459650.jpg?crop=0.781xw:0.739xh;0.109xw,0.0968xh&resize=480:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Mazda MX-5 Miata</div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="cont-checkbox">
      <input type="radio" name="myRadio" id="myRadio-2" />
      <label for="myRadio-2">
        <img
          src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/2020-chevrolet-corvette-c8-102-1571146873.jpg?crop=0.548xw:0.411xh;0.255xw,0.321xh&resize=980:*"
        />
        <span class="cover-checkbox">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 12 10">
            <polyline points="1.5 6 4.5 9 10.5 1"></polyline>
          </svg>
        </span>
        <div class="info">Toyota Supra</div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```