# How to add image instead of checkbox's options in contact form 7?

Tags: html, css, contact-form-7

I want to add images instead of checkbox but the functionality would be the same as the checkbox.

I have tried many options but not found any of the solutions.

Comment: your images is static or dinamic?

Comment: static images..

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663562/use-images-like-checkboxes

Comment: just check this link out https://www.bigdataguys.com/contactus/ ... Check the contact form's image section. I want something similar to that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use images like checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663562/use-images-like-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to hide your `input` checkbox element and style custom pseudo-elements.

This is probably the best StackOverflow answer:
[How to style a checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

It all starts with:

```
input[type=checkbox] { appearance: none; }
```

And you can style from there. Another StackOverflow answer: [Pure CSS Checkbox Image replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772273/pure-css-checkbox-image-replacement)

Make sure you use the CF7 classes.

Comment: This may be helpful but this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663562/use-images-like-checkboxes is working in codepen but not on website

Comment: Check your class names from Contact From 7. That might be affecting the styling. Can you edit your question to provide the code you're currently using?

Comment: Thanks for your response.